# Trouble clearing variable input for button in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

I'm making a button that appends a text input to  list and hopefully more later.  Everything seems to be working well, except once the input is cleared, you can hit the button again and it will repopulate with the same variable value, even if i change the variable. My text input is #MercInt. Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var $inputVal = $("#MercInt").val();
  var list = "#intList";
  var listItem 

  function mercList (){
    listItem = "<li>" + $inputVal + "</li>";
    $(list).append(listItem);
    }

  function mercWarning (){
    };


  $("button").on("click", function (event){
     event.preventDefault();
     if (!$inputVal) { mercWarning()
      } else {      
       mercList()
       $("#MercInt").val("");
       listItem = ("Doesn't matter what I put here");
       }
  }) // end button.on.click

}); //end of doc.ready
```

I'm new to this, so if you also have any general comments on the code, feel free.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only setting $inputVal when the page loads, not each time the button is pressed.

Move the setting of $inputVal into the click handler and all should be well.

```
$("button").on("click", function (event){
 event.preventDefault();
 var $inputVal = $("#MercInt").val(); //Add this line
 if (!$inputVal) { mercWarning()
  } else {      
   mercList()
   $("#MercInt").val("");
   listItem = ("Doesn't matter what I put here");
   }
})
```